# Predicting (X,Y) from (X,Y,time) regression

Tags: python, regression

I have 3 vectors: x position, y position and time.

I did a 3D regression in python with the following code:

```
from scipy import interpolate
reg = interpolate.BivariateSpline(x, y, t, kx=1, ky=1, s=0)
```

This is a linear 3D regression.
Now `reg` is a class instance of BivariateSpline "trained" with the `x, y, t` data set.

My intention is to obtain an `x, y` tuple of values given a value of `t`, but I cannot do that since the class asks me for two input values (Quite logically, now I think about it).

But my question remains, since what I want is quite intuitive if one sees it; what would be the x, y position for a given time in the regression?

Is Regression a good method, or shall I use something else?

**[EDIT]**

I want to predict a future x, y position by introducing a future value of time, and I want to do that using a 3D linear regression, or any other suitable method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understnad your question, but if you have `(x,y,t)` and you want to grab only `(x,t)` you can do

```
[(x,y) for (x,y,t) in reg]
```

Comment: Well, perhaps my question was not clear enough, I want to predict a future x, y position by introducing a future value of time, and I want to do that using a 3D linear regression (or what ever else)